# Can selenium click somewhere which is out of view

Tags: selenium, testing

I have a code where it is identifying the button but not able to click on it ,may be because it is not in view.If we scroll it clicks.Can selenium click which is out of view

Comment: What code? What have you got so far? Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

If element is on the page but not on the screen, selenium should click it without problems. Maybe your button is not on page at time of click?

Comment: I was actually taking coordinates and clicking on it.So it was not clicking on it.When I tried with only click it worked

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the library you are using. E.g. nightwatch tries to scroll the element into view before clicking

```
.click()
Suggest edits

Simulates a click event on the given DOM element. The element is scrolled into view if it is not already pointer-interactable. See the WebDriver specification for element interactability.
```

https://nightwatchjs.org/api/commands/#click

I believe Mink2Selenium does not.

but if the element is not reachable by scrolling, selenium will not be able to click it, same as a user would not be able to click it. What is good, because selenium is used to do as much as possible realistic tests